# Eigenfunctions of Parabolic Differential Operator`

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, parabolic-pde

Suppose that $L$ is a parabolic differential operator, is there a stable numerical scheme for finding eigen-functions of $L$?  Here the domain of interest is a closed, bounded, convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

In fact, I'm looking for the eigen-function corresponding to the minimal eigenvalue, with Dirichlet boundary condition on the boundary of $D$.

Comment: On what sort of domain do you want to find eigenfunctions? Spectral theory is heavily dependent on the domain your operator lives on.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I modified my question to include that information.

Comment: In that case you might have a problem, because already the go-to example of a parabolic differential operator (heat flow: $u_t - \Delta u = 0$) [has no eigenfunctions on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$](https://mathoverflow.net/a/98191/127579).

Comment: I modified the question a tiny bit to resolve this issue